# Count each day with SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display a table with SQL query like this:

[image]

I have run my query:

```
select 
    tb_r_orderdata.finishtime as date ,
    count(*)sum all,
    sum(when status = 'SUCCESS' and issync = '1' then 1 else 0 end) sumpaid,
    sum(when status = 'SUCCESS' and issync in ('3', '4') then 1 else 0 end) sumfail,
    sum(when status = 'CLOSED' then 1 else 0 end) sumclose,
    sum(when status = 'Null' then 1 else 0 end) sumunflag
from 
    tb_r_orderdata;
```

But when I execute it, the result is different than what I expected. The result is like this:

[image]

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `GROUP BY` and the `CASE`:

```
select tb_r_orderdata.finishtime as date ,
       COUNT(*) as sumall,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status='SUCCESS' AND issync='1' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumpaid,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status='SUCCESS' AND issync in ('3','4') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumfail,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status='CLOSED' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumclose,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status is null then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumunflag
from tb_r_orderdata
group by tb_r_orderdata.finishtime  ;
```

MySQL treats booleans as integers in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  You can simplify your query to:

```
select o.finishtime as date ,
       COUNT(*) as sumall,
       SUM(status = 'SUCCESS' AND issync = '1') as sumpaid,
       SUM(status = 'SUCCESS' AND issync in ('3', '4')) as sumfail,
       SUM(status = 'CLOSED') as sumclose,
       SUM(status is null) as sumunflag
from tb_r_orderdata o
where tb_r_orderdata.finishtime is not NULL
group by o.finishtime  ;
```

This also removes `NULL` finish times.

Comment: ya, i mean Null is NULL.
Nah i see, i forgot to use group by as you said,thanks for your answer. I want to accept this answer but i have to wait in 7 minutes. thank you so much. but there is a problem in the top of table there is a record like this.

Comment: check out the answer above, because in comment i cant upload image so i add in answer. thanks you so much

Comment: The `NULL` record is because `finishtime` is `NULL`.  You could filter that out by adding `where finishtime is not null` to the query.

Comment: `select tb_r_orderdata.finishtime as date ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status='SUCCESS' AND issync='1' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumpaid,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status='SUCCESS' AND issync in ('3','4') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumfail,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status='CLOSED' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumclose,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status='NULL' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumunflag
from tb_r_orderdata
group by tb_r_orderdata.finishtime 
where tb_r_orderdata.finishtime is not NULL`  . but all i got is syntax erorr. can you explain it why

Answer (score 0):

[image: Explanation in comment for Gordon Linoff]

Explanation in comment for Gordon Linoff

i have try your answer but there is record NULL in the top of table, i dont know why, can you explain it

with little bit change from Gordon Linoff answer

```
select tb_r_orderdata.finishtime as date ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status='SUCCESS' AND issync='1' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumpaid,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status='SUCCESS' AND issync in ('3','4') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumfail,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status='CLOSED' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumclose,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status='NULL' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumunflag
from tb_r_orderdata
group by tb_r_orderdata.finishtime
```